# Where's the best place to implement frequent object properties filling

Tags: php, symfony

We are developing an application in Symfony (2.7) that deals with third party entities and usually needs to transform (or fill) objects from one subsystem to another.

Take this example where we need to fill `$destinationObject` with data stored in `$sourceObject`:

```
$sourceObject;
$destinationObject = new DestinationObject();

$destinationObject->setProperty01($sourceObject->getProperty01());
$destinationObject->setProperty02($sourceObject->getProperty02());
$destinationObject->setProperty03($sourceObject->getProperty03());
$destinationObject->setProperty04($sourceObject->getPropertyWithDifferentName());

$intermediateValue = explode('/',$sourceObject->getProperty04());
$destinationObject->setProperty05($intermediateValue[0]);
$destinationObject->setProperty06($intermediateValue[1]);
```

Manual method (or no method) leads to duplicated code, copy&paste practices, etc.

So my question is:

**Where is the propper place to implement this kind of "transformations"?**

My ideas so far:

- Doing it as a model method like `$destinationObject->loadFromSourceObject($sourceObject)` is a bad idea (entity coupling)
- I don't like the idea of building an utility class full of static methods
- ...

**EDIT:** Also, there's a common situation where in `$destinationObject` we need to load data from both `$sourceObjectFromClassA` and `$sourceObjectFromClassB`, so  `SourceObjectToDestinationObjectTransformer` understood as a method returning a new created `DestinationObject` is not a valid option. I mean, something like this may be needed (bad code coming warning, just for exemplification purpose):

```
$destinationObject = new DestinationObject();
$destinationObject->loadFromSourceClassA($sourceObjectFromClassA);
$destinationObject->loadFromSourceClassB($sourceObjectFromClassB);
```

Comment: Upvoted as I have been wondering this as well. I still recommend to rephrase the question, as `best way to do x` is rather broad and invites opinion-based answers, which is off-topic here. You point out hard requirements you want to avoid, which still makes it valid in my opinion.

Comment: More on topic, I have been looking into [ParamConverters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) for this issue.

Comment: You could use a `SourceObjectToDestinationObjectTransformer` service and then create your entity from that. That way the entities aren't coupled but the build method in encapsulated. If you used an interface for type hinting you could always change the method (or remove the conversion entirely) it at a later date and just change the service without needed to update all of your code.

Comment: Symfony transformers are generally considered to be bi-directional.  Not sure if that is a requirement here.  Maybe a DestinationFactory::createFromSource($source) would work.

Comment: I didn't mean transformer in the "Symfony form model/view transformer" sense. The word "transformer" is just a technical term here as that is what it would be doing.. "converter" could be another name I guess.

Comment: Edited to try to explain some situation where may be @qooplmao solution is not valid.

Comment: Having two source objects does not make much difference.   DestinationFactory::createFromSources($sourceClassA,$sourceClassB); Having said that, you really should rethink your design.  This sort of pattern is rarely needed.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, rethinking my design is part of my question, but keep in mind that I don't have any control over SourceClasses as they come from third party subsystems that can not be changed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really seeing an issue with multiple sources. You could even do something like `$destination = new Destination(); $sourceToDestinationTransformer->updateDestinationFromSourceA($destination, $sourceA); ... and so on`. The main thing from your end is to not couple your entities. At some point you will need to couple your service to the external source, but if you use an interface the only hard coupling (in your code typehints etc) will be to your interfaces so it will only directly depend on internal classes/interfaces.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think a service able to fill a `destinationObject` (or to create it) is the best idea so far.